# EOL Notice: Utopic (14.10) has now reached End of Life

Tags: discussion, scope, end-of-life

This is a notice regarding releases of Ubuntu that have reached end of life.

The following versions of Ubuntu and derivatives are officially **end of life** as of July 23, 2015:

- Utopic 14.10

New questions regarding the above posted after the aforementioned date may need to be considered **off-topic**.  Old questions (posted before the end of life date) that are still being answered regarding these releases should have a comment included on them about upgrading to a supported release to continue to get support for their versions of Ubuntu.

This information can be confirmed on the **[official Ubuntu Wiki page that lists all current, development, and end-of-lifed releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)**

<sub>The date "July 23, 2015" was established based on the EOL [Announcement message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-July/000198.html).</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today, July 23, 2015, is the day that 14.10 Utopic reached End of Life.

While this means **new** questions (stressing the **new**) about 14.10 are off topic, older questions (both answered and unanswered) that were around before the EOL date should not be closed or deleted.

**This is done here with the consensus of the moderators which is that the primary reason for is not supporting EOL releases is because those versions no longer receive updates to repair bugs or malfunctioning packages, nor security updates and support, and you should not use those versions because of the lack of security updates.  This is not just my opinion, but has reached some consensus here on meta in other threads.**

Note that 12.04, 14.04, and 15.04 remain all currently supported.

---

*If you have an issue with how we handle EOL releases, you need to bring up this issue in a different thread.  This thread here is NOT a valid thread for arguing against the EOL policies.  This thread is simply a notice that, in accordance with the current moderation policies, these questions are offtopic because of the End of Life date.*

Comment: Well, in addition to security problems, there are also bugs. If you have a bug in a program foo, and you file a bug report, the very first step is to install the most recent version of foo as newer versions are likely to fix bugs and it is difficult to impossible to find upstream support for old versions.

Comment: 1 comment: the bold part has been proven wrong with 14.10  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2015-July/003054.html  14.10 got updated AFTER it went EOL. 2 reasons: severity of the bug and the high 14.10 userbase.

Comment: Another comment: 12.04.2 12.04.3 12.04.4 are EOL too. 12.04.1/12.04.5 ends april 2017.

Comment: @Rinzwind Don't you have edit privs?

Comment: sure but this is meta ;)

Comment: *Takes off pencil rubber in passing of utopic*